# why is this LinkedList locked in a empty while loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

Question solved! thank you guys. See the answer by myself below

==================

In a method i wrote this:

```
while (queueP.isEmpty()) ;
```

queueP is a LinkedList and there is another thread trying to locked it and write into it. I want to make sure queueP is not empty first and go next. But the codes ends up as a dead loop. jstack shows that this while loop locked queueP so the writing thread is always waiting to lock it and there is nothing writen into queueP and the loop just never ends.

here is what's in the jstack result:

```
"c2-0" #11 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001d51b800 nid=0x46a0 runnable [0x000000001de4e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at dbq.DoubleBufferQueue.take(DoubleBufferQueue.java:44)
    - locked <0x000000076f2083b8> (a java.util.LinkedList)
    at dbq.Test$ToyConsumer.run(Test.java:91)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"p2-0" #10 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000001d519800 nid=0xbc4 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000001dd4e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at dbq.DoubleBufferQueue.put(DoubleBufferQueue.java:33)
    - waiting to lock <0x000000076f2083b8> (a java.util.LinkedList)
    at dbq.Test$ToyProducer.run(Test.java:58)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

DoubleBufferQueue.java:44 is the while loop.

so, why is this list locked in a while loop? is it some kind of feature of JVM?

======================================================

`put()` and `take()` are:

```
 @Override
    public void put(T e) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        synchronized (queueP) {
            queueP.offer(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T take() throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        synchronized (queueC) {
            if (queueC.isEmpty()) {             
                while (queueP.isEmpty()) ;
                synchronized (queueP) {
                    Queue<T> tmp = queueC;
                    queueC = queueP;
                    queueP = tmp;
                }
            }
            return queueC.poll();
        }
    }
```

I read about double buffer queue today and i'm trying to write one myself(Could someone tell me if this is the right name?). It's just a simple demo. I know the switch in `take()` looks very dangerous and ReentrantLock will be much better but I'm just so curious... So i created only one consumer and one producer, but the problem still exists.

And does jstack show the exact line where list is locked? I do not know much about that. Line 44 is just the while loop.

Comment: [Read the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html): "Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a linked list concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally." Without synchronization, there is no guarantee that `queueP.isEmpty()`'s value will be re-checked once the loop is entered.

Comment: You should probably post more code. You may also want to look into concurrent collections, e.g. in your case maybe [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html).

Comment: `isEmpty()` does not take a lock, so the fact that your code does have a lock on the `LinkedList` means that you have taken it, e.g. by having a `synchronized (queueP) { ... }` around the displayed code. *That* is what took the lock, and you loop is unaware, so it won't release the lock, preventing your `put()` method from adding anything. As suggested in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37395357/5221149), use a concurrent list, and remove your `synchronized` blocks. Or at least show us the *relevant* code so we can help you.

Comment: Now that we see the code, and given the fact that jstack shows both `take()` and `put()` locking in the same object, it would appear that `queueP` and `queueC` both reference the *same* LinkedList. Could be the result of a race condition caused by inadequate synchronization, e.g. the unsynchronized use of `queueP`.

Answer (score 3):

[Read the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html):

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized**. If multiple threads access a linked list concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally.

Without synchronization, there is no guarantee that `queueP.isEmpty()`'s value will be re-checked once the loop is entered.

As @Mena suggests, you should look at collections specifically designed for concurrent access instead, in the `java.util.concurrent` package.

Comment: Given that it seems like OP wants to hold there until there's something in the queue, I'd recommend looking at one of the [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) implementations, and use `take()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know about concurrent collections in JDK. In fact I'm trying to write a double buffer queue(not sure is this name right in English), as you can see in the java file name. So I'm trying to implement synchronization myself. And I do not lock this list before the loop because that's what I'll do after  confirming this list is empty. What's most important is, I'm now extremely curious why this happens ^_^

Comment: @HeKunxi `isEmpty()` doesn't lock. Are you *sure* you didn't synchronize on the list? How about you show us the full `take()` and `put()` methods?

Comment: @Andreas take() and put() are added to the question.

Comment: @HeKunxi you won't (necessarily) get an up-to-date value of `isEmpty()` unless you invoke it in a block `synchronized` on `queueP`. And you also can't currently guarantee that `queueP` is not empty when you enter the swap `synchronized` block, since the emptiness check and synchronized block are not atomic.

Answer (score 0):

Now I know why this falls into dead loop sometimes.

Key point is that, **the first thread trying to lock a object does not necessarily acquire the lock first.** And two operations will not be reordered only when they meet the "Happens-Before" relationship.

So this is what happened right before a dead loop begins, given a consumer thread "c2-0" and a producer thread "p2-0".

1. c2-0 locked both queueC and queueP, but it's suspended right after `queueC = queueP`and before `queueP = tmp;`.
2. p2-0 `put()` tried to lock queueP, suspended.
3. c2-0 resumed and finished this call of `take()`. Soon c2-0 begin the next `taken()`, trying to lock queueC which was also required by p2-0 because queueC and queueP both reference the same LinkedList when p2-0 got stuck.
4. c2-0 acquired the lock before p2-0, though it required later. And the consumer began a dead loop.

**what I learned from this:**

1. ReetrantLock is a much better choice than synchronized, especially when references may be changed.
2. **Never** forget "Happens-Before" and never suppose there is any other order between threads
3. jstack dose not mean `while(queueP.isEmpty())` locked the list. In fact its' result says "Thread c2-0 holds a lock on queueP and it's running at line 44 now"， which is totally irrelevent. What a misunderstanding.....